# Time complexity for two nested loop for a specific case

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, nested-loops

I have a function `test(arr, x)` where `arr` is the array of finite size and `x` is the finite positive number. I have two nested for loops as below:

```
function test(arr, x) {
    for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++) { //executes arr.length times
        for(j=1; j <= x; j++) { // executes x times
            //code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**:
What is the time complexity for this case? I'm confused between O(n) and O(n^2).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a good answer, there'd need to be more information. Is there any bound on either the length of the array or the value x? If not, then technically you would call that O(N*M), especially if one of the values is significantly different in magnitude from the other. If either of the values has a known fixed limit, then O(N) would be a more applicable way to analyze the algorithm, since there's really only one variable affecting overall complexity. If both values are unbounded and typically large, I'd just call it O(N^2). ...

Comment: … The goal of big-O notation is to gain understanding of the general form of the algorithm, so while there are some technicalities that are important to follow, the most important requirement is that your analysis accurately reflects the true cost of the algorithm at scale, and especially that your analysis for one implementation of an algorithm is comparable to another competing implementation, i.e. you're able to accurately judge the true relative difference in complexity. If you've achieved that, don't sweat too much the small details.

Comment: Assuming `x` has no dependence on the size of the array `n` and vice-versa, the complexity should be `O(n*x)`.

Comment: `x` doesn't depend on `arr` and vice-versa. Overall, the inputs of the function depend on the user.